# how to change/Append the value of label according to radio button in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
protected void Rb1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    RadioButton rd = (RadioButton)sender;
    switch(rd.Text)
    {
        case "Liner":
            int a = 0;

            lbResult.Text = Convert.ToString(a);
            int lbltxt1 = Convert.ToInt32(lbResult.Text);
           lbltxt1 = lbltxt1 + a ;
            lbResult.Text = Convert.ToString(lbltxt1);
            break;
        case "Glossy":
            int b = 40;
            int lbltxt2 = Convert.ToInt32(lbResult.Text);
            lbltxt2 = lbltxt2 + b;
            lbResult.Text = Convert.ToString(lbltxt2);
            break;
        case "Matte":
            int c = 30;
            int lbltxt3 = Convert.ToInt32(lbResult.Text);
            lbltxt3 = lbltxt3 + c;
            lbResult.Text = Convert.ToString(lbltxt3);
            break;
        case "Dull":
            int d = 20;
            int lbltxt4 = Convert.ToInt32(lbResult.Text);
            lbltxt4 = lbltxt4 + d;
            lbResult.Text = Convert.ToString(lbltxt4);
            break;
        case "Woove":
            int f = 60;
            int lbltxt5 = Convert.ToInt32(lbResult.Text);
            lbltxt5 = lbltxt5 + f;
            lbResult.Text = Convert.ToString(lbltxt5);
            break;
        case "Laid":
            int g= 45;
            int lbltxt6 = Convert.ToInt32(lbResult.Text);
            lbltxt6 = lbltxt6 + g;
            lbResult.Text = Convert.ToString(lbltxt6);
            break;
    }


}
```

In this, if I selected a radio button named **"Glossy"** then the value of lbResult label become 40 but if I change or reselect another radio button like **"dull"** then its adds the value of dull and Glossy(40+20=60)and label shows 60.
I want if I reselect any other radio button the value just become the value of that radio button in place of adding both the value
eg: if I select "dull" after "Glossy" the value of label become 20

Answer (score 0):

Include lbResult.Text = "0"; At the beginning of the Rb1_CheckedChanged event.

```
     protected void Rb1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            lbResult.Text = "0";
...
```